# How do I convert a R to a C?

Tags: haskell, hmatrix

How do I convert a `Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static.R` to a `Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static.C` (with all imaginary parts being zero?).

Sounds like a straight forward problem, but from what I see all `map-like` functions have the same input as the output field. Eg:

```
dvmap :: (...) => (field -> field) -> vec n -> vec n
zipWithVector :: (...) => (field -> field -> field) -> vec n -> vec n -> vec n
```

This is making it impossible to convert from `R` to `C`.

I guess I am just missing something here?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with those types. I can only see `extract :: R n -> Vector ℝ` and `create :: Vector ℂ -> Maybe (C n)` that could help, even if we need to pass though the "size-unchecked" vector. This is, of course, assuming that we do have a conversion `Vector ℝ -> Vector ℂ`.

Comment: @chi That's what I am doing at the moment. But it feels like a lot of unnecessary conversion for what is basically just a type conversion.

Comment: `Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static` generally seems to be pretty focused on Euclidean spaces, and only supports some complex  stuff for eigenvalues. Strange that this conversion in particular isn't included; I guess it might be worth filing a pull request for it.